# Identifying IC w/ marking "501 115"

Tags: identification

I have a rail of unidentified SOIC-8 ICs with marking

```
501  
115
```

Nothing else. No manufaturers logo, no nothing. Does anybody know what this could be?

**edit**
(picture added)
At 3mm they're quite high for SOIC-8, so they could be optocouplers or so?

[image]

Grid is 5mm. (Yes, I know the devices aren't properly aligned, but I did this on my scanner with a sheet of paper over the devices...:-))

**update/conclusion**
It's almost certainly an Agilent HCPL-0501. The marking matches completely: the `501` refers to the type number, the `115` means week 15 of the year 2001. And the date code appears below the type number (which was a problem with the TR115).
Also diode tests all pass. The 5-6 test which passed was an error; I probably held the testprobe on pin 6 and 7 simultaneously, and 5-7 is the transistor's base-emitter diode.
Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Could you use measured grid paper in the picture or measure them off and give dimensions.

Comment: Use a diode function on a meter and see what's connected where.

Comment: If that's 5mm grid, those aren't MSOP (0.65 mm pitch), they're SOIC (1.27 mm).   They look way to big, even setting aside height, to be MSOP anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with a similar component, but finally I found it.  You were right; it is an optocoupler: HCPL0501.  Check the [Fairchild HCPL0XXX datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/HC/HCPL0531.pdf).

If you want to look for similar components just type HCPL-0xxx and the mark code on your IC.  Good luck!

Comment: A promising candidate, however please refrain from using all capital letters as it coveys the impression you are shouting.

Comment: Link seems to be dead, but I found the datasheet [here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/HC/HCPL0501.pdf). This one has very complete information on device marking (wish they were all so detailed), and it doesn't fit: it lacks the Fairchild logo, and the assembly package code. May be the same device from another manufacturer, actually the type number reminds me of HP. Passes the diode test on pins 2-3, but also on 5-6 :-(

Comment: Found an HP, erm, Agilent, erm [Avago datasheet](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0171EN). Marking matches completely!

Answer (score 3):

A [TR115 optocoupler](http://www.ssousa.com/pdf/TR115.pdf)?

Ringing out a suspected optocoupler/isolator with a multimeter is a slight step above reading a passive.  They are almost always isolated from side to side, so you only have 12 possible combinations for each 4-pin side.

Comment: Looks like an optocoupler to me, too. I guess you're right, and I also guess the part was assembled in the 1st week of 2005 (-> 5 01 -> 501)

Comment: @zebonaut: I've been thinking about a date code too, but that usually appears below the part number, which would then be 501, week 15 of 2001.

Comment: It passes the diode test on pins 5-6, but fails on pins 1-2. It may be a TR115, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could be these low cost digital isolators:
http://www.nve.com/Downloads/il5xx.pdf

Or something similar...

Comment: I'm afraid not. I corrected the package, it's MSOP rather than SOIC, but they're higher than IL5xx. Were you thinking about them because of the "511"-"115" similarity? It's most definitely "115", as you can see in the picture. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: Yeah, bad guess - never mind.

Answer (score 0):

From size I'd say optoisolator - easy to confirm - infinite resistance across body, about 1v diode drop on LED.
Another possibility is inductor/transformer. Maybe crack one in half with sidecutters...